# Joomla translation file does not translate all words

Tags: joomla, translation, ini

I am trying to translate an component (Jomsocial). The file that i try to translate in en-GB.com_community.ini.
My problem is that some words are not translated.
Jomsocial 3.2 with Joomla 3.7
Any idea? 
Thanks!

Comment: Check that the translation does not have any strange characters, in this case the translated word will not be considered

Answer (score 0):

1. Download text editor with a “Find & Replace” function. We recommend Notepad++ or Atom which are both free.
2. Search for \"*QQ*" and replace it with \" (Do this first. It will fix most issues.)
3. Search for *QQ* and replace all occurrences with *QQQ*
4. Search for \" and replace all occurrences with \"
5. Save the file and test it.